# Intel XDK IoT Edition maxBuffer on Edison

Tags: intel-xdk, intel-edison

I'm using Intel XDK IoT Edition to build and upload a project to Intel Edison. This project requires some external libraries that are packed in the package.json file. With the latest version of the XDK, whenever I try to build or upload the project, the following error occurs:

Intel XDK - IoT App Daemon (requires Intel XDK IoT Edition greater than 075) v0.0.31 - commands: run, list, debug, status

UPLOADING: Uploading project bundle to IoT device.
ERROR: Error extracting update - Error: stderr maxBuffer exceeded.

Any idea what could it be provoking this? How can I increase the maxBuffer?

Answer (score 0):

go to your project root and delete the whole **node_modules**
 directory. Next, click on the Install/Build icon (the sun like one).

Also you can run

```
node clean cache
```

on the Edison device

Comment: I tried it already but it didnt worked. Only worked destroying and recreating the whole project. Thank you for you time